# getting familiar with characters of groups

Tags: group-theory

What is the best reference to get familiar with characters of groups?

A reference with many examples and an amateur language is preferred.

(I am a beginner in algebra)

Comment: What do you mean by characters of groups? Do you mean character table?

Comment: If you are a beginner in algebra and you are referring to characters of groups, then forget it. You should first learn group theory, linear algebra, ring theory and field theory. After that you can appreciate books by M.I. Isaacs *Character Theory of Finite Groups* or J.P. Serre *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*.

Answer (score 0):

Dummit and Foote has a decent section on characters at the end, not sure if thats the level you're looking for though. I guess I'm curious in what context you would run in to characters without much algebra. If you want to learn about Dirichlet characters (a special case of the more general notion of characters), Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory has a really great section on those, which does not assume any knowledge of group theory.

Comment: I have coding theory course with no previous algebra knowledge.

Comment: Actually I want to read [Bent-Function Sequences](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1056589)

Comment: Well then I suppose I would first suggest getting a working familiarity with groups. Any introductory abstract algebra book would do fine for this (Fraleigh, Herstein, and Artin are all good). Once you've read through the sections on subgroups and group homomorphisms maybe try reading the section of Apostol I recommended? The difficulty in what you are trying to do is that group characters belong to a field known as representation theory, which relies heavily on the machinery of groups and algebras. Most texts discussing them will assume you have a substantial algebra background.

Comment: I know groups, fields , spaces , ... . What is the best for homomorphism?

Comment: Well that depends on how much depth you want. Fraleigh is a good introductory text, whereas Dummit and Foote is extremely thorough and more advanced. Both are great though.

Comment: what is the name of books by Fraleigh and Apostol ? Thanks

Comment: Fraleigh is "A first course in abstract algebra" and the Apostol book is "Introduction to analytic number theory" but there is only a very small section of that book devoted to characters.